# what is happening with order of print fields in awk

Tags: awk

There must be something simple I'm missing!

Have a test file (test.txt):

```
10  20  a 
11  30  b   
12  40  c
```

When I enter:

```
awk <test.txt '{print $0,"x"}'
```

I get:

```
x      20      a
x      30      b
x      40      c
```

I'm expecting:

```
10  20  a   x
11  30  b   x
12  40  c   x
```

Comment: Pretty sure you want the awk command on the left side of <

Comment: Welcome to SO @RustyC please check my answer once and let me know if that helps you?

Comment: could be your data file has DOS line endings, with `\r\n` pairs. Clean it up with `dos2unix myDataFile.txt` . Good luck.

Comment: Yep - converted to unix EOL and things went as expected.  Still can't see how the DOS EOLs stuffed things up. Can you explain?

Comment: `\r` is carrige return, it just moves the "cursor" to the left margin, while `\n` is "line-feed" and it moves the line down. In Windows/DOS you need both to get to the "front" of the next line, in *nix, the `\n` just assumes going to the front of the next line. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should try code as follows:

```
awk '{print $0,"x"}' OFS="\t" Input_file
```

It gives me your expected output as follows.

```
10  20  a       x
11  30  b       x
12  40  c       x
```

When I tried your command it gives me same output too, could you please check `cat -v Input_file` to see in case you have any carriage returns in your Input_file?(as a check I am asking) in cade they are there you could remove them by doing `tr -d '\r' < Input_file > temp_file  &&  mv temp_file  Input_file`